# Facebook JS API - Page keeps refreshing

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I have some problem with logging in, using Facebook JS SDK.

Well, when user enters page, it keeps refreshing - `window.location.reload();` in `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login'...` is getting fired, even if user haven't logged in.

Here is my script:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : '445298832195237', // App ID
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
    {
        $.ajax({async: false,
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://hfyt.pl/fb_register.php',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //alert(data); 
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

You can try it live at http://hfyt.pl/ (just uncomment window.location.reload() using some debugger). I'm using Chrome.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish. I don't believe that FB.Event.subscribe is what you're looking for here.

Comment: @TwisterMc I want to refresh user's browser when he logs in via Facebook. When I commented out the `window.location.reload()`, there is no refresh-loop, but then there is no refresh at all.

Comment: @Kacper well, you are refreshing the page after the user logs into facebook. But after a page reload, he isn't logged in anymore so the same thing happens again. You need to store the login via PHP, localStorage, Cookies or whatever. Or just don't rely on `location.reload` which would be the far better choice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, this is what's happening:

1. your page DOM loads
2. JS SDK loads asynchronosly
3. once it's loaded, it checks logged in status
4. on `connected` status, it refreshes the page, and steps 1-4. repeat

..and this is happening on every page load, not just 1st. To avoid this, I suggest you..

- either store the status in something that survives page refresh, i.e. localStorage
- or rewrite your code so that id doesn't rely on window.document.reload()

Comment: My code was ok, but some day I entered it and the refresh-loop started.

Comment: @Kacper your code is not ok. That's exactly whats happening. You login with facebook, the page reloads. You login again, the page reloads and so on. You created a loop and that's whats happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use FB.getLoginStatus for checking if people are logged in or not on page load. However, keep any redirects out of this.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Then use FB.Event.subscribe to only listen for when users login and their response changes.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {  // reload here });
```

I think that'll do it.